# How to search and edit excel files fast in Openpyxl

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I've 2 worksheets. I need to compare each cell in the sheet 'Data' (350k rows, string) with cells in another sheet, 'Dictionary'. If the string is not in 'Dictionary' or is in the 1st column of 'Dictionary', do nothing. If it is present elsewhere in 'Dictionary', take the value in the corresponding first column. Then go to 'Data' and write it next to where it was initially present in 'Data'.

As mentioned in the title, the problem is speed. This code works for a test file of around 150 rows, but takes 4 minutes to do so. So, it is infeasible to use it for my file. Please tell me how I can speed it up. This is my first python code.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Test.xlsx')
first_sheet = wb.sheetnames[0]
Data = wb.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)
second_sheet = wb.sheetnames[1]
Dictionary = wb.get_sheet_by_name(second_sheet)

for rownum in range(2,Data.max_row+1):
  var1 = Data.cell(row=rownum, column=1).value 
  for rownum1 in range(2,Dictionary.max_row+1):  
    var2 = Dictionary.cell(row=rownum1, column=1).value 
    for colnum2 in range(2,Dictionary.max_column+1):
      var3 = Dictionary.cell(row=rownum1, column=colnum2).value 
      if var1 != var2 and var1 == var3:
       Data.cell(row=rownum, column=4).value = var2
       wb.save('Test.xlsx')
      else:
         None
```

Comment: The slowness is due to you constantly looping through the second sheet. You only need to do this once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problems by using a hashset, which will let you check for values being present in constant time.

Edit: You wanted a more specific example

Imports and setting up your files:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Test.xlsx')
first_sheet = wb.sheetnames[0]
Data = wb.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)
second_sheet = wb.sheetnames[1]
Dictionary = wb.get_sheet_by_name(second_sheet)
```

Read each value in Dictionary into memory, creating a dictionary data structure that matches each value in Dictionary that isn't in the first column to the value of the first column in that particular row.

```
Dict = {}

for row in range(2, Dictionary.max_row + 1):
    for col in range(2, Dictionary.max_column + 1):
        cell_value = Dictionary.cell(row=row, col=col).value
        Dict[cell_value] = Dictionary.cell(row=row, col=1).value
```

now iterate through Data and perform your operations using Dict:

```
for row in range(2, Data.max_row+1):
    for col in range(2, Data.max_column + 1):
        cell_value = Data.cell(row=row, col=col).value
        if cell_value in Dict: #if it was elsewhere in Dictionary
            #I'm not sure what you meant by next to so here it just overwrites
            #The value with the corresponding 1st row in Dictionary
            Data.cell(row=row, col=col).value = Dict[cell_value] 

wb.save('Test.xlsx') #save once at the end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried to rewrite my code using the hints you have given me, but I haven't been able to write a working code. Could you please elaborate a little? I believe I understand the general idea you imply, but I am failing at the execution. I am sorry, I am very new at this. For example, I tried loading the 2nd sheet into memory and printing it out. It prints a disordered list- how then, if the string is present in 'rest_of_second_sheet', take the value in the corresponding first column- as in how do I identify the string's location?

Comment: Thank you. I was able to generate the key-value pairs in the dictionary. But these are reversed. For example, samsung: sumsing is showing up as sumsing:samsung (of these, Samsung, which is the correct spelling, is present in the first column, and sumsing is present in one of the other columns of the same row). This is an important difference, because I need to paste Samsung in the first sheet, not sumsing.

Comment: when you find sumsing in your other excel file, you will put it through the dictionary. Lo and behold you get sumsing:samsung and samsung is the result. Replace sumsing with the result of the dict and you are done

Comment: I added this line and it exchanged the keys and values {v: k for k, v in Dict.items()}. Is there a way to get it in the correct way directly?

Comment: You want to be able to pass sumsing into the dictionary and get samsung as the result, not the other way around.

Comment: The last part of the code, where it iterates through Data, does not seem to change the excel file in any way. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not trying to be rude but the working code is right there. You just have to copy and paste it.

Comment: Yes, I have run the code multiple times. It creates the dictionary, but doesn't change the excel. I even checked the directory to see if I was using the wrong file, but everything seems in order. What you explained reg. key-value makes sense- thank you.

Comment: do you have the wb.save part

Comment: Yes. It's working perfectly now- the problem was wrong column numbers in this line "for col in range(2, Data.max_column + 1):". My data is in the first column. Thank you so much for such a elegant program- I hope to learn enough to help someone else like this some day- you have been very patient. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a bit late but in case anyone is having the same trouble...
I had the same issue so i transformed the excelsheet in a numpy 2D array, the search goes waaaaaaaaay faster. This is a modification of my code for the OP's problem:

```
file = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, data_only=True)
WS_Names= file['Names'] #Worksheet containing the names
NP_Names = np.array(list(WS_Names.values)) #Transformation to numpy 2D Array
WS_Dict = file['Dict'] #Worksheet containing the data
NP_Dict = np.array(list(WS_Dict .values)) #Transformation to numpy 2D Array

names = NP_Names.T[0] #Take the first column containing data

for idx, name in enumerate(names):
    locations = np.column_stack(np.where(name == NP_Dict))
    for row, col in locations:
        if col != 0: # The first column
             WS_Dict.cell(row=idx+1, column=4).value = var2NP_Dict[row,col]
```

Hope it helps you :)